# Problem in RStudio with the dplyr package

Tags: r, dplyr

Every time I try to load a package using `library(dplyr)` it gives me this error

> message error: there is no package called ‘crayon’

I'm not sure what to do I have installed the packages.

Comment: What version of R are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You might also try installing another package that includes dplyr (like tidyverse) https://www.tidyverse.org/packages/

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
```